# Renaming a local stack variable with IDAPython

Tags: ida, idapython, stack-variables, idc

I am trying to write an IDAPython script that renames some local variables (in the disassembly window) according to some logic, unfortunately I am unable/failing to use the API to do so...

In my searches I found that set_member_name should be used since the stack frame is treated like a structure from IDA's POV, but again the documentation is not clear about how I can name a variable in a certain stack frame (or any structure for that matter)...

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you precise if this is for the disassembly window or for the pseudocode window (decompiler)?

Comment: For Disassembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to write a function that is doing what I was looking for...
sharing my code below:

```
def rename_stack_variable(func_addr, var_name, new_var_name):
    func = idaapi.get_func(func_addr)
    frame = idaapi.get_frame(func)

    offset = 0x0

    for i in range(0, len(list(frame.members))):
        if var_name == get_member_name(frame.id, offset):
            break
        offset = i * 4

    set_member_name(frame.id, offset, new_var_name)
```

Comment: ** a small comment on my code above is that I assumed that all the stack variables are 4 bytes, which is not necessarily true but worked on my case, so if you/someone has a better solution I would be happy to hear :)

Answer (score -2):

```
    my_rename <- function(df, varname) {
  varname <- ensym(varname)
  
  df %>% 
    rename(!!varname := cyl) %>% 
    group_by(!!varname) %>%
    summarize(mean_mpg = mean(mpg))
}

my_rename(mtcars, cylinder)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  cylinder mean_mpg
     <dbl>    <dbl>
1        4     26.7
2        6     19.7
3        8     15.1
```